# HTML5 empty <time> tag for date of publication

Tags: datetime, time, html

I'm confused about HTML5 `<time>` semantic tag. It seems to me it's for tagging strings such as "today", "last Christmas", "10.10.2010", "2am" etc. to help machines recognize and understand them. All valid examples I could find on HTML5 Doctor and W3C page were like:

```
<p>I have a date on <time datetime="2008-02-14">Valentines day</time>.</p> 

<p>We open at <time>10:00</time> every morning.</p>
```

But what if I want to set article publication date (e.g. to help Google robots), but without any string displaying it? Would it be valid to have:

```
<article><time datetime="..."></time> content </article>
```

or:

```
<article><time datetime="..." /> content </article>
```

or should I do that some other way?

(It seems hilarious to me to have e.g. `<time datetime="...">...</time>` and CSS `display:none` for `time` selector...)

Comment: Do you mean that if you include a `<time datetime="..." pubdate="pubdate"></time>` empty tag inside an `<article />`, the value of `datetime` is still used as the publication date of that article?

Comment: ^ Note that `pubdate` is probably not valid. I can't find it in the specs anymore (this changed a couple times before).

Comment: Yes, `pubdate` is already deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `time` element contains the datetime value in machine-readable (the `datetime` attribute) and human-readable (the text content) formats.

> The datetime value of a `time` element is the value of the element's `datetime` content attribute, if it has one, or the element's `textContent`, if it does not.
>
> [WHATWG](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element)

So if the `datetime` attribute is absent, the datetime value will be parsed from the text content.

If the `datetime` attribute is present, you are free to write anything into the text content, or nothing in your case.

Comment: So `<time datetime="..." />` would be correct in this case?

Comment: As far as I understand - yes.